# FXImageView : Image changed at URL does not updating in imageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have an `FXImageView`. I load Image by passing the URL of the Image but the problem is that if Image at the server changes it does not reflect in change in image in image view. It still showing old image. I think it might be caching image at URL and showing without getting updated image.

What I should do get updated image from server?

My Code Below:

```
self.userPhotoImageView.asynchronous = YES;
self.userPhotoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
NSString *imagePath = //constant image url path to server
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];
[self.userPhotoImageView setImageWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's by design. FXImageView caches images indefinitely. You can clear them on the client-side by manually removing the image from the FXImageView cache, or by modifying the cache key, but FXImageView does not provide any method to detect if the image has changed on the server, because once an image is downloaded it doesn't make any further network requests for that URL (that's kind of the point).

If you change the image on the server, you should change the filename/URL as well so that it won't be cached. If you can't or don't want to do that, you'll probably need to modify FXImageView, or look for a different solution.

If you need to use FXImageView's special effects rendering, one option would be to download your images separately using another library (e.g. AFNetworking or SDWebImage) and then just insert the image into FXImageView using the setImage: method instead of setImageWithURL: